# How to use this.Dispose() from a Thread (Not main thread)

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, dispose

How can I dispose a WinForm from a Non-Main Thread?

I have several threads running that are checked for `.IsAlive` from within another thread in a loop. Then I try to dispose them after they all die but it is not working as I envisaged, how do I dispose correctly?

Comment: You MUST dispose them from the UI thread. You will have to rethink your design.

Comment: Ah I see, alright a timer control did the trick then - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to interact with WinForms from non-UI thread you can use [Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.8) method. Next example create a form, shows it and then call dispose on it

```
public class DisposeFormDemo
{
    private class MyForm : Form
    {
        public MyForm() => Text = $"Main thread id = {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}";
    }

    public delegate void MyDelegate(Form form);

    public static void Main()
    {
        var form = new MyForm();

        Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(3000).ContinueWith(_ =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Task thread id = {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

            var myDelegate = new MyDelegate(f =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Current thread id = {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                f.Dispose();
            });
            form.Invoke(myDelegate, form);
        }));

        form.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

As you can see delegate will be executed on UI thread